$\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(u+c)^2} e^{-m(\frac{1}{u+c} + n(u+c))} \, du$ using complex analysis
The integral I'm trying to evaluate is:
$\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(u+c)^2} e^{-m(\frac{1}{u+c} + n(u+c))} \, du$, where $m,n,c > 0$.
Normally for these kinds of integrals, I've seen people use keyhole contours to try to evaluate the real line integral using the residue theorem. However, with regards to the keyhole contour, it seems that the larger arc of Radius $R$ would tend to blow up as $R \rightarrow \infty$, as values with negative real part would be in the exponent, making the exponent positive with the other negative factors there.
Would anyone have any advice/suggestions on how to proceed?
Thanks.
